# Old MYSQL query to MYSQLI query functions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have quite a bit of functions that need to be changed to MYSQLI.

Could someone please help in the proper recode? Fixing this will enable to change the rest of functions with this issue. Thank you.

Errors start with an ** and end with ** with the problem line followed.

connection.php

```
<?php

mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info') or die($connect_error);


 ?>
```

general.php

```
<?php

function sanitize($data) {
    mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data);
    }

function protect_page() {
    if (logged_in() === false) {
    header('Location:../../redirect.php');  
    }   
}

function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) {
    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php');
    exit();
    }
}

?>
```

users.php

```
  <?php

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    mysqli_num_rows($query), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}

?>

    mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info') or die($connect_error);


     ?>
```

login.php...Here is where I am trying to echo if the user exists, should be returing the user 'stole' but it is not. BTW, the form is good, have checked that already.

```
<?php
    include 'core/init.php';

if (user_exists('stole') === false) {
    echo 'exists';
}
die ();


if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors [] = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors [] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered? '; 


    }
}    

?>
```

init.php

Comment: "mysqli" is different from "mysql-api" (old). It was not just an "i" added are new methods.

Comment: you're not passing the correct arguments. Show exactly what you're passing to them.

Comment: It's obvious, you're not passing DB connection to your functions.

Comment: Downvote for a LEGIT comment on covnerting over to MYSQLI?? Ok. BTW, I have to tried to research this and have had no luck, that is why I always ask here.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, if that's the case then that's easy, I need to know now about the 1 expected 2 given on num_rows.

Comment: Because, your syntax (and question) is malformed. Why don't you show us the actual/full code you're using and we'll take it from there ;) You may even have a scope issue.

Comment: Dear colleague, **mysqli API** is new and it is different from the old **API**, therefore the method of use is different, not only just add the letter *I* in all methods, read the documentation, see examples of how to use. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-, edit, all code there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Will definitely read into that

Comment: All those functions in which `$connect` is now needed, must be defined to accept `$connect` as a parameter. `function user_exists($username, $connect) {}`

Comment: You have no `$connect` to call your DB connection. All you have is `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info') or die($connect_error);` not to mention `$connect_error` being a stray variable. This is a debugging question with too many things wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your script:

1. `$connect_error` is undefined. (related by @Fred-ii-)
2. You are using sessions `$_SESSION['id']`, there is no indication of `session_start();` being used. It is required inside all files using sessions. (related by @Fred-ii-)
3. You did not add the resource to a global variable, the methods you created will never get access to `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info')`.

### Read about variables scope:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

### Read about sessions:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Try this:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info') or die($connect_error);


 ?>
```

general.php

```
<?php

function sanitize($data) {
    global $connect;
    mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data);
    }

function protect_page() {
    if (logged_in() === false) {
    header('Location:../../redirect.php');  
    }   
}

function logged_in_redirect() {
    if (logged_in() === true) {
    header('Location: ../../dashboard.php');
    exit();
    }
}

?>
```

users.php

```
  <?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'info') or die($connect_error);

function user_exists($username) {
    global $connect;
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    mysqli_num_rows($query), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: OP's `$connect_error` is a stray variable which will not catch the actual error, should there be one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assumed that it was a custom variable. Okay, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome Guilherme. I didn't want to go anywhere near answering this question (*fearing it would bite me in the "you know what"*), because of the multiple errors. I hope OP accepts your answer; which looks promising. *Cheers* - will +1 though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your words, listening so I will always seek to improve and engage constructively. You proves to be a great person.

Comment: You're welcome and that's quite nice of you to say so Guilherme, thank you. *Cheers*

Comment: An added note. Since OP is using sessions `$_SESSION['id']`, there is no indication of `session_start();` being used. It is required inside all files using [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).